# Powershell - remove files

Tags: powershell

This script will only delete files if all exists. How to rewrite the script, so it will delete files even one of the file is missing.

```
$paths = $outpath, $outPath2, $outPath3
if ((test-path $paths) -notcontains $false){
Remove-Item -Path $paths 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is the error exception when it doesn't find a file , you can use the remove-item parameter -erroraction silentlycontinue :

```
 $paths| % { Remove-Item "$_" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  }
```